# Array to sting conversion notice. Why?

Tags: php

Why I'm getting, *Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/test2.php on line 11*, Notice ?

```
$users=array('aa-a', 'b-bb', 'cc-c');

foreach($users as $usr)
{
$var = htmlspecialchars(htmlspecialchars($usr));
$z = explode('-', $var);
echo "$z \n";
}
```

Can't figure out why I'm getting this, *gettype($var)* echoes string.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlspecialchars()` twice?

Comment: $z is an array, that is what explode() returns

Comment: Your code snippet has only 8 lines.  Hard to know which line is line 11.

Comment: Sorry, didn't post the whole thing. I know $z is an array. The notice is about this line $z = explode('-', $var); For some reason it doesn't explode $var. It thinks that it's an array. Why so ?

Answer (score 4):

Your variable $z is a new array. When you try to

```
 echo "$z \n";
```

It will give an message about it being an array. You could instead display $z with something like the following:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($z,true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't post the whole thing. I know $z is an array. The notice is about this line 
$z = explode('-', $var);

For some erasn it doesn't explodes $var. It thinks that it's an array. Why so ?